# I just installed oracle 11g and I can't figure out how to log into the enterprise manager.

Tags: user-accounts, oracle-11g

Any idea what the default login is? None of my oracle accounts are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, I got it, you have to log in as SYS as sysdba. I swear I had tried that, but it works now.

Comment: I also tried a lot but its not working for me. Can you please tell me what all changes you have done for that. I am able to log in as SYSMAN with Normal privileges. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With the password you just gave during setup (not the one you gave the website when you downloaded).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to unlock the SCOTT/HR/whatever schema you've created / want to work on.

Login into SQL*Plus as sysdba and then proceed with

```
ALTER USER <USERNAME> ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Once unlocked, login to the Enterprise manager, the default URL should be `http://<ip-address-of-database-server>:1158/em`

Comment: I did that. I made my own user account, and I just unlocked scott, set his password, granted all privileges to him and it still says login operation failed. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'm too new to this to know...

Comment: what privileges have you granted ? Can you login via SQL*Plus using that account ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to login with scott/hr/whatever schema. Then login with SQL*plus using that account by just going to

```
http://localhost:5560/isqlplus
```

`localhost` represents your system. You can enter the IP address of the database server if you are  remotely accessing the database. In connect identifier add database name (for example `orcl`),
we can access a normal user like hr or scott, because these users don't have access to manipulate the database.

That's why they can't work on em:1158. Only limited users like sys/system can access on em:1158 to manipulate the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and struggled quite a bit searching for any document regarding this.

Actually I got it worked using the **SYSMAN** username, providing the same password which was asked while installing the 11g R2, which is asked right after when it asks for the email and all for updates regarding product. And logged in using the above credentials as **Normal** type.

The other usernames such as **SYS**, **SYSTEM** etc didn't worked for me as both Normal or SYSDBA type.